# Http Request Basic

Tags: android, mysql, json, http, request

I'm trying to make a little Android application which should catch a page of my website and show the content (plain text) on my application.

The website I call will only send the message I need, so I have to cut the HTTP Header somehow off and show the body. But I don't know how to do this and need your help. How can I get the text from a basic website and show it in my Application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Httpcomponents library.
http://hc.apache.org/.

I use this to communicate to my RESTful services.

There are examples on how to get the response string only( ignoring http headers and stuff)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use this approach:

```
DefaultHttpClient http_client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet http_get = new HttpGet( YOUR_SERVER_URL );
HttpResponse response = http_client.execute(http_get);
if( response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200 ) {
    return "Error: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
}
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
String first_line = reader.readLine();
```

and then you may read the rest of lines similar way from the `reader` in a similar fashion.